# I have a problem with HDMI sound on both Ubuntu 14 and Windows 7, is this hardware?

Tags: nvidia, sound, hdmi

I have a problem with HDMI sound on both Ubuntu 14 and Windows 7, is this hardware?

The problem only occurs when running games (something sound intensive) I get ugly noise through the speakers. This also occurs in Windows and didn't until a couple of months ago.

Switching to optical stereo has resolved the issue but I have lost 5.1 sound.

I think it may be the hardware itself since this is a new problem and is common to 2 Operating Systems. I also think this because HDMI sound is relatively simple to do.

I have a Geforce 670 GTX and is fairly new, still in warranty, does this sound like a hardware problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It sounds like a hardware problem as it persists regardless of operating system. This does not necessarily mean the your 670 GTX is faulty. Try a different (known working) cable. If you get the same result with a known good cable, you know where the problem is.

Comment: I've tried re-seating the card, but not changing the cables (it runs through my amp). I'll give that a go, thanks.